# Is there any delphi winsock2 library?

Tags: delphi, winsock2

i need to use WSASocket function etc ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[WinSock 2.2 API unit](http://home.earthlink.net/~akonshin/files/ws2rev3.zip)
or  [Winsock2.pas](http://files.codes-sources.com/fichier_fullscreen.aspx?id=17675&f=WinSock2.pas&lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

Another good higher level wrapper around WinSock2 is [Synapse](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/download).  It also can support Winsock 1 with a compiler switch.  The nice thing about Synapse is that it takes much of the pain out of socket programming away and is very easy to use and extend.  Many of the necessary functions have already been implemented, which will save you time getting your solution up and running.